# Excel name manager reference contains indirect path in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cell A1 in Sheet1 pointing to the path to a folder containing txt files.

> Sheet1!$A$1 = C:\Excel\folder\

I have defined a name in Name Manager which pulls the list of txt files from the folder.

> Name1=FILES("C:\Excel\folder*.txt")&T(NOW())

This gets the list of the txt files from the folder.
I want to replace

> C:\Excel\folder\

with

> Sheet1!$A$1

in the Name1 formula. 
I tried to put it in the normal way, I get errors.

here is the site, I got this formula from
[Link to the site](http://www.exceltoxl.com/index.php?p=98&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1)

Can somebody help me to replace this in the right way?
Thank you.

Comment: what is `FILES` you are using? Is it function of some sort. And are you using code to insert formula?

Comment: it is not a function. As far as I know, it is used to get the name of the file from a folder.
and in my excel sheet, I put =IF(ISERROR(INDEX(FL;ROW()-2));"";INDEX(FL;ROW()-2))  where I want my file names to appear.

Comment: whats with the index usage here? And AFAIK still not sure about using `files`. Can you post a ref link showing its syntax pls?

Comment: In your post, you use `C:\Excel\files*.txt` for `Name1`, which would return all files within the C:\Excel\ folder that begin with the letters "files."  Are you looking instead for all TXT files within the C:\Excel\Files\ folder?

Comment: I edited the source of confusion. Actually the word "files" in the folder path is not related to the "files" in the formula.

Comment: i added a [link] (http://www.exceltoxl.com/index.php?p=98&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) to a site that explains this function in detail

Comment: Are you getting Name1 value? where you use this/these value? upload screenshot of your sheet if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula will return an array of text files within the `C:\Excel\folder\`, when used in Name Manager:

```
=FILES(Sheet1!$A$1 & "*.txt")
```

I'm unsure what you're doing with `T(NOW())`.  The `NOW()` function returns the current date/time.  The `T()` function returns its argument if it is text – otherwise it returns "" (empty text).  Since Excel stores date/times as numbers, `T(NOW())` will always return "".

If you want it to return the current date/time, you could do something like this:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```

So your named formula would be:

```
=FILES(Sheet1!$A$1 & "*.txt") & TEXT(NOW()," mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```